# Creating a panel for displaying default information in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, android-actionbar, kivy, kivy-language

I'm new to kivy. Currently working on building an application in kivy.

My need to is to display some default information on top of the application (say for example., date, time ..)
Please suggest me a way to do that

I came across action bar in kivy but unable to add that in my currently built application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way that I would approach this is to create a row of labels at the top of your screen. One would display the date, the next would display time, etc. Use the Kivy clock to update them every second.

Comment: thank you .. what if I need to place a panel on top of the application, that is fixed ? (similar to notification panel in android mobiles) 

The need of the panel is to display a series of information

Comment: Yes. You can set Labels, just like Buttons to fixed locations on your GUI. I'm assuming that is what you want to do.

Comment: actually I'm looking for all the available options to fulfil my need.

I'm building an car control interface. So I need a panel on top to display Date&Time, Temperature, Fuel, Range. (Suggest me a way for the panel or bar )

Later in the layout I'm adding the slider to to control the movement of the car.